# How to determine the latest major and full kernel version string as compactly as possible

Tags: bash, sed, grep, cut, archlinux

So what I'm intending to do here is to determine both the latest major and the full kernel version string as compactly as possible (without a zillion pipes to grep).

I'm already quite content with the result but if anybody has any ideas how to squash the first line even the slightest it'd be very awesome (it has to work when there are [no minor patches](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20120807125753/http://kernel.org/) as well).

The index of kernel.org is only 36kB compared to the 136kB of that of http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/ so that's why I'm using it:

```
_major=$(curl -s http://www.kernel.org/ -o /tmp/kernel && cat /tmp/kernel | grep -A1 mainline | tail -1 | cut -d ">" -f3 | cut -d "<" -f1) 
pkgver=${_major}.$(cat /tmp/kernel | grep ${_major} | head -1 | cut -d "." -f6)
```

Comment: Mainline or stable?  Your code seems buggy so I can't tell which you intended.

Comment: Ugh, parsing the frontpage is going to be a pain.  Can you assume you'll have `git` on the machine?  If you do, it would be better to handle the output of `git ls-remote -t git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git`

Comment: +1 for git; the home page *might* be lying.

Comment: @John Zwinck, well, no, it's not buggy :D. I'm grepping the _major string from after the first line that says 'mainline' just because that's the heading it has in http://www.kernel.org (just click and have a look). Also there's the dot (.) after the `major` variable in `pkgver` so that might have been a clue of some kind. @Josh Coartwright, lol yeah I've noticed. Well that's awesome. Frankly didn't even cross my mind but since I'm only looking for the stable releases I'm assuming it has to be: `git ls-remote -t git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git`?

Comment: @Det, yes, that should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a thought exercise at this stage as the real answer is in the comments above, but here are some possible improvements.

Original:

```
_major=$(curl -s http://www.kernel.org/ -o /tmp/kernel && cat /tmp/kernel | grep -A1 mainline | tail -1 | cut -d ">" -f3 | cut -d "<" -f1)
```

Use tee instead of cat:

```
_major=$(curl -s http://www.kernel.org/ | tee /tmp/kernel | grep -A1 mainline | tail -1 | cut -d ">" -f3 | cut -d "<" -f1)
```

Use sed to minimise the number of pipes, and to make the command unreadable

```
_major=$(curl -s http://www.kernel.org/ | tee /tmp/kernel | sed -n '/ainl/,/<\/s/ s|.*>\([0-9\.]*\)</st.*|\1|p')
```

Cheap tricks: shorten the URL

```
_major=$(curl -s kernel.org | tee /tmp/kernel | sed -n '/ainl/,/<\/s/ s|.*>\([0-9\.]*\)</st.*|\1|p')
```

Comment: Awesome. I just wish I could rate your answer as such.

Comment: `curl -s kernel.org | sed -n '/ainl/,/<\/s/ s|.*>\([0-9\.]*\)</st.*|\1|p'` alone does the same, unless you need to save that file `/tmp/kernel`

Comment: @Martin Canaval, yeah, I do, as already stated a couple of times =).

Answer (score 3):

kernel.org provides a plaintext listing of all the current versions at https://www.kernel.org/finger_banner

For mainline:

```
curl -s https://www.kernel.org/finger_banner | grep mainline | awk '{print $NF}'
```

For latest stable:

```
curl -s https://www.kernel.org/finger_banner | grep -m1 stable | awk '{print $NF}'
```

The mainline and latest stable versions will never be EOL, but other versions often are, so the above awk commands will not work correctly for all versions. A general solution as a bash function:

```
latest_kernel() {
    curl -s https://www.kernel.org/finger_banner | grep -m1 $1 | sed -r 's/^.+: +([^ ]+)( .+)?$/\1/'
}
```

Examples:

```
$ latest_kernel mainline
4.18-rc2
$ latest_kernel stable
4.17.3
$ latest_kernel 4.16
4.16.18
```

Comment: Very nice, with something alternative added.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a [useless use of cat](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html). You can replace:

```
cat /tmp/kernel | grep -A1 mainline
```

with simply:

```
grep -A1 mainline /tmp/kernel
```

In your case, you don't even need the file at all. Curl by default will emit to standard output, so you can just do:

```
curl -s http://www.kernel.org/ | grep -A1 mainline
```

Comment: Well, yeah, thanks but dwurf's answer is better :D. I'm saving it to a file because I need to use it in both variables and I only wanna fetch it once (also the reason why I was using http://www.kernel.org (36k) instead of http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/ (136k))

Comment: Sorry, I missed that the file was used again.

Comment: @Det i see you were simply passing on the buck, LOL!

Comment: @Det if you pass on the buck you should pass back the blowback ;p

Comment: @randomstring well sort of. I've had that "award" given to me before but then forgot about the whole thing. Just makes me smile thinking about the whole thing so I just decided to "pass it on".

Comment: Belatedly, [a Stack Overflow post about useless `cat`s](/q/11710552)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Justin Brewer's answer, you probably want to know when a kernel is EOL since this is useful information... the following single awk command preserves all this information for you.

```
latest_kernel() {
    curl -s https://www.kernel.org/finger_banner |awk -F ':' -v search="$1" '{if ($1 ~ search) {gsub(/^[ ]+/, "", $2); print $2}}'
}
```

- -F ':' -- field separator because everything after the : is the version string.
- -v search="$1" -- pass search string as an awk internal variable
- if statement -- check if field $1 matches the search string
- gsub -- in-place modify of field $2 to strip leading spaces

Then just print field $2 for any matching records (I presume your search string will only match the left-hand side of one line... if it is important to exit after the first match, use `print $2; exit`)

Search string can include spaces, etc. Use of awk variables and matching with `~ variable` instead of pattern-matching '.../'"$1"'/...' avoids the need to exit single-quote mode and avoids syntax errors where the search string contains "/".